# Homotopy quantum field theories as functors

Tags: category-theory, mathematical-physics, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, quantum-field-theory

A homotopy quantum field theory is a symmetric monoidal functor $\tau:\mathrm{HCobord}(n,X)\to\mathrm{Vect}_{\mathbb{K}}$, with $X$ a path connected space with basepoint $\ast$. There is the following diagram (see [page 15 of this ArXiv article](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.QA/0105018)):
\begin{multline}
\begin{matrix}
\mathrm{Cobord}(n) &\rightleftarrows\space \mathrm{HCobord}(n,X) &\longleftarrow& \pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)\\ \searrow & \downarrow & \swarrow & \\ & \mathrm{Vect}_{\mathbb{K}}\\ &\downarrow&\\& \mathrm{Set}
\end{matrix}
\end{multline}
A homotopy QFT restricted to domain $\pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)$ is a contravariant functor $\pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)\to\mathrm{Vect}_{\mathbb{K}}\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Set}$, which is a locally constant sheaf on $\pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)$, i.e., a sheaf of sections of a covering space of $\pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)$. Let us denote by $\mathrm{LSheaf}\pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)$ the category of locally constant sheaves on $\pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)$. Then, $\mathrm{LSheaf}\pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)\hookrightarrow \mathrm{Sh}\pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)\hookrightarrow \mathrm{PSh}\pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)$.

**Proposition:** *Loops on $\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)$ are $X$-cobordisms, since $\pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{HCobord}(n,X)$.*

> *Is the above proposition and the above argument correct?*

In the [following article](http://www.ams.org/samplings/math-awareness-month/06-stringessay.pdf), it is written that a string connection assigns to a loop a vector space and assigns to cobordisms between loops, linear transformations. Hence,

> *Does it follow that string connections defined on the associated vector bundle over $\pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)$ as defined in the article above are all homotopy quantum field theories restricted to domain $\pi_1\mathrm{Map}(S^n,X)$? **What exactly would it mean for a string connection to be a HQFT?***

Answer (score 3):

A loop on $\text{Map}(S^n,X)$ is just a map $S^{n+1}\to X$. So it is an $X$-cobordism, though one without boundary, i.e. a cobordism between $\emptyset$ and $\emptyset$. An $n$-dimensional HQFT assigns the base field $k$ to $\emptyset$ and so multiplication by an element of $k$ to such a loop. On the other hand an $n+1$-HQFT will assign a vector space to such a loop seen as an $X$-manifold. So this latter is the case relevant to your second article. In a rough sense your second question then follows, although I see no reason a string connection should extend to an HQFT in general.

Comment: +1 for answering my first question. The last sentence is exactly the reason why I posted the question here. I guess I was a little vague in my second question - along with that question, I also meant to ask "what exactly would it mean for a string connection to be a HQFT?"

Comment: That's a question for an expert. I don't see any particular reason it should have a nice answer, but perhaps someone will be able to be more helpful.